# How to Expand TreeView in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, treeview

I have following Code:

```
    self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
    self.model.setRootPath(dirPath)  
    self.model.setNameFilters([content]) # FILTER
    self.model.setNameFilterDisables(False) # FILTER
    self.emp.treeViewFolderView.setModel(self.model)
    index = self.model.index(dirPath)
    self.emp.treeViewFolderView.setRootIndex(index)
    self.emp.treeViewFolderView.setColumnWidth(0, 380)
    self.emp.treeViewFolderView.setColumnWidth(3, 130)
    self.emp.treeViewFolderView.setColumnHidden(1, True)
    self.emp.treeViewFolderView.setColumnHidden(2, True)
```

I want to expand the treeView, ive done these things:

```
self.emp.treeViewFolderView.expandAll()
self.emp.treeViewFolderView.setExpand(index, True)
self.emp.treeViewFolderView.expand(index)
```

but these things didnt work.
I think i missed something. But what? Thanks for the Help :)

i Tried now few more things.
If code an extra button with expandAll() it works.
But it dosnt work if i expand all within the complete code

Comment: Connect your model to directoryLoaded and do the expandAll() in there.

Comment: As explained in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#caching-and-performance): "QFileSystemModel uses a separate thread to populate itself so it will not cause the main thread to hang as the file system is being queried. Calls to rowCount() will return 0 until the model populates a directory." This means that when you call `setExpand()` and the target directory has not been loaded in the model yet, it won't expand anything (and that index is also probably invalid too).